# Can't correclty initialize AttachedProperty set in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

Spent hours searching for an answer but had no luck to break this puzzle yet.

I have an attached property which is a `ObservableCollection` and I need to get the host UIElement for the attached property to initialize this collection correctly.

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Content", typeof(AnimaCollection), typeof(UserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new AnimaCollection(), BehaviorPropertyChangedCallback));
```

```xaml
<Button Width="80" Height="30">
    <core:AnimaBehavior.Content>
        <core:AttachedAnima ToValue=".3" />
        <core:AttachedAnima ToValue="1"/>
    </animaCore:AnimaBehavior.Content>
</Button>
```

I have `BehaviorPropertyChangedCallback` specified but it is not firing when collection is set in XAML. I can't set property default value to `null` as it will fail at runtime while trying to add new items into a null. Also if I specify `AnimaCollection` in XAMl with underlying `AttachedAnima` items and set default prop value to `null` the callback will not fire again.

I need to somehow get the parent UIElement I'm attaching to. So the collection items can get a reference to an object to work with. Any help on how this can be done will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback is only invoked when the property changes. When assigning a new collection to the property the callback gets invoked. When adding items to the collection only the collection's `CollectionChanged` event gets triggered instead (since it is an `ObservableCollection`). This means the `BehaviorPropertyChangedCallback` gets never called in your case. You should add a second attached property e.g. called `IsEnabled` and add a callback to it e.g. `InitializeOnAttached()`. The moment you set it on the element like `AnimaBehavior.IsEnabled = "True"` the `InitializeOnAttached()` callback gets invoked and you can access the attaching element by casting the `DependencyObject` parameter.

```
public class AnimaBehavior
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Content", typeof(AnimaCollection), typeof(UserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new AnimaCollection(), BehaviorPropertyChangedCallback));

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(UserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, InitializeOnAttached));

  public static void SetContent(UIElement element, AnimaCollection value)
  {
    element.SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
  }

  public static AnimaCollection GetContent(UIElement element)
  {
    return (AnimaCollection) element.GetValue(ContentProperty);
  }

  private void InitializeOnAttached(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (d is Button attachingElement)
    {
       // Use or store Button
    }


    // Or access AnimaCollection or subscribe to CollectionChanged of AnimaCollection 
    if (d is UIElement attachingElement)
    {
       // Or access AnimaCollection or subscribe to CollectionChanged of AnimaCollection 
       AnimaCollection contentCollection = AnimaBehavior.GetContent(attachingElement);
    }
  }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<Button AnimaBehavior.IsEnabled = "True">
    <core:AnimaBehavior.Content>
        <core:AttachedAnima ToValue=".3" />
        <core:AttachedAnima ToValue="1"/>
    </animaCore:AnimaBehavior.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks, It is valid solution but another attached property adds complexity and clutter. Sadly it is not user friendly and I wonder if different approach can solve this problem. Anyway, if there will be no better answer I'll accept yours.

Comment: @AlexanderSmirnov I was adapting to your implementation. Binding a collection from a view model to the attached property would trigger the `Content` callback. But it's impossible to suggest a different approach than yours without knowing further details. What is the goal? Why don't you simply extend the Button and give it a collection property directly? Why does your button require a collection property at all?

Comment: It is an animation extension which can be attached to different controls. So I need an agile approach without the parent control modifications.

Comment: You better create a style or `Storyboard` that defines some `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` based animations. But this isn't 'agile' enough? I don't think an attached property is the right way at all. Also because you define the collection in XAML (inline and not inside a view model) this won't work like you expect it. As I wrote in my answer, this way the `PropertyChangedCallback` will never get invoked. But a binding would trigger the event.